# How to pass a C# string array to JavaScript using JSExport in WebAssembly?

Tags: javascript, marshalling, webassembly, .net-7.0

Following is the boilerplate example from `VS2022 WebAssembly console` template. I'm trying to extend it to pass a C# array to read from the JS. I'm very new to WebAssembly, your help would be much appreciated.

##### C#

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript;

public partial class MyClass
{
    //Working
    [JSExport]
    internal static string Greeting()
    {
        var text = $"Hello, World! Greetings from node version: {GetNodeVersion()}";
        return text;
    }
 
    //Working
    [JSImport("node.process.version", "main.mjs")]
    internal static partial string GetNodeVersion();


    // This is not working
    [JSExport]
    internal static string[] GetArray()
    {
        return new string[] { "1", "2" };
    }
}
```

##### JavaScript side

```
import { dotnet } from './dotnet.js'

const { setModuleImports, getAssemblyExports, getConfig } = await dotnet
    .withDiagnosticTracing(false)
    .create();

setModuleImports('main.mjs', {
    node: {
        process: {
            version: () => globalThis.process.version
        }
    }
});

const config = getConfig();
const exports = await getAssemblyExports(config.mainAssemblyName);
const text = exports.MyClass.Greeting();

//How to read the array? 
//This is not working
const strArray = exports.MyClass.GetArray();

console.log(text);

await dotnet.run();
```

Comment: According to:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/import-export-interop?view=aspnetcore-7.0

You must MarshalAs to a string array.

The Array of column indicates if the .NET type can be marshalled as a JS Array. Example: C# int[] (Int32) mapped to JS Array of Numbers. 

Not sure if this applies to Exports but maybe?

Comment: @dynamiclynk this is Webassembly but a Blazor example would be helpful if you have one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Found the issue**

I was using the `WebAssembly Console App` project template in VS2022 .net7 and it was missing the `static Main()` method suitable for an entry point.

Just add the following to the `MyClass` fix the issue.

```
internal static void Main()
{

}
```